# The activity option is not appearing under New<File. hence not able to add a new activity to my project

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, configuration

[the problem here starts from the File>New and then we have options like new module and project but no activity hence not able to create activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1ZQS.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly but if you want to add a new activity make a **"right click"** on a folder in your projectexplorer, select **new** and there in the menu you find "activity".